# Can I reference the contact ID of the Current Employer with a Drupal entity token?

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicrm-entity

I'm trying to create a link to a CiviCRM-integrated Drupal webform that passes the ID of a contact's employer

I'm trying to use

http://somedomain.org/node/9999?cid1=[current-user:civicrm-contact:employer-id]

but the token replacement is blank. [current-user:civicrm-contact:employer-id] also does not work. However, [current-user:civicrm-contact:current-employer] does replace with the *name* of the current employer.

Comment: Gosh I didn't even know tokens like that existed. What module is generating them?

Comment: and this can't be done without tokens by putting the Contact's ID in the url and setting cid2 to be filtered based on the relationship?

Comment: The CiviCRM Entity module is where those tokens come from.
https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity

Comment: Also, I'm trying to use the token to CREATE the value for cid1=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up using Markup field in the webform with some PHP code that made a CiviCRM API call:

```
<?php
$params = array(
  'version' => 3,
  'is_active' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id_a' => $_SESSION['CiviCRM']['contact_id'],
  'relationship_type_id' => 4,  // Employee Of
);
$result = civicrm_api('Relationship', 'get', $params);

if ( ! $result['is_error'] ) {
  $employer_id = array_shift($result['values'])['contact_id_b'];
}

if ( $employer_id ) { ?>
    <input onclick="location.href='/link-to-webform?cid1=<?php echo $employer_id ?>';" type="button" value="Manage Contacts" />
<?php }
```

I'm going to file an issue on the module.

Comment: That's very cool!

Comment: This will only be correct if there is only 1 employer. If there are multiple employers this will give rather randomly the one that sequential finds first.