# Employer ID token not working with Mosaico

Tags: civimail, tokens, mosaico

I'm composing an email with Mosaico that requires the following tokens:

{contact.display_name}

{contact.contact_id}

{contact.current_employer}

{contact.current_employer_id}

The first three tokens work as expected, but {contact.current_employer_id} does not.  Whenever I attempt to use it nothing is returned.  I did ensure that the individual had proper editing permissions over the employer.

I tested the token in a 'traditional' CiviMail mailing, and it works as expected.

Any ideas as to what might be going on or suggestions to try?

Using Mosaico version 2.4.1592820024

Comment: I think there is some bug with the api concerning getting the current employer_id of a contact. I'm getting no result with api3 and a "Forbidden" with api4. There are some other issues indicating this at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/can-i-reference-the-contact-id-of-the-current-employer-with-a-drupal-entity-toke and https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=36760.0.html